# Reactjs - MUI HTML Tooltip is not working with dynamic HTML content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using customized HTML MUI [Tooltip](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/). It is working with static content. I want to make it dynamic. It is not working with the dynamic html content.

I am trying the following way.

```js
const ADJUSTMENT_HELP_TEXT = styled(()=>(
    <Typography component="div">
        <em>Adjustments can be added as following.</em>
        <ul><li>You can include previous due amount.</li><li>You can exlude amount.</li><li>You can add Waive-Off etc.</li></ul>
    </Typography>
))


const HtmlTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }) => (
  <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
  [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f9',
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
    maxWidth: 220,
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(12),
    border: '1px solid #dadde9',
  },
}));

return <>
<HtmlTooltip  
    title={<Fragment>{<ADJUSTMENT_HELP_TEXT />}</Fragment>}>
    <HelpTwoToneIcon /> 
</HtmlTooltip>
</>
```

**UPDATE**

It is working fine if I prefer static content as follows:

```js
<HtmlTooltip  
    title={<Fragment>
            <Typography component="div">
                <em>Adjustments can be added as following.</em>
                <ul><li>You can include previous due amount.</li><li>You can exlude amount.</li><li>You can add Waive-Off etc.</li></ul>
            </Typography>
    </Fragment>}>
    <HelpTwoToneIcon /> 
</HtmlTooltip>
```

I want to make the content dynamic.

**MUI Refr.**
It looks like this on MUI [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/)
[image]

> Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-zeh-xcmk0y?file=/demo.js)

Comment: What is the `HtnlTooltip` component in your example? can you create a codesandbox with your code?

Comment: I have updated my question regarding `HtnlTooltip` . we can it is styled component. also explained here https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/

Comment: @Sabbin sanbox code is added in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with styled material ui, but this worked :

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-shockley-t1z6t0?file=/demo.js

```
const ADJUSTMENT_HELP_TEXT = styled(() => (
  <Typography component="div">
    <em>Adjustments can be added as following.</em>
    <ul>
      <li>You can include previous due amount.</li>
      <li>You can exlude amount.</li>
      <li>You can add Waive-Off etc.</li>
    </ul>
  </Typography>
))(); //just added the ()
```

Comment: Why do you need the styled here? it doesn't seem to style anything

Comment: @Sabbin The styled() utility lets you add dynamic styles based on a component's props. You can do this with dynamic CSS or CSS variables. More you can get here https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/

Comment: @paulo I was close. Thanks for the help. (y)

Comment: I know what it does, I was wondering why the OP is using it in that context. it's not styling anything with it in the `ADJUSTMENT_HELP_TEXT` const. It's just returning a wrapped component with nothing